# Wallpaper flickering

Tags: macos, software-update, bug

I've noticed after updating to the latest OS X update 10.10.3 my *desktop* wallpaper flickers frequently.

The flickering will momentarily go if I have a window cover the location of flickering but it will appear again about 10 minutes later.

Could someone tell me how to resolve this? or at least troubleshoot the issue.

I have a Mac Mini (Late 2012).

UPDATE:
Screenshot of my console as requested:
[image: screenshot of console]

2ND UPDATE:
Added screenshots of my screen settings and new [console log](http://pastebin.com/M4ZR95EX).
[image]
[image]

Comment: 2 questions to clarify. what wall paper, and what does your console says looking at the "windowserver" is it switching/showing up constantly in the console log. type "WindowServer" in the filter to see it.

Comment: I have updated my post with answers to your post.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the Console log:

I see two item making problems with the User Interface (UI) in (WindowServer)

One is the VLC.app and the second one is the "Transmit application"

I know what is VLC app, so just disable (remove) it to test. (then download updated version)

Second one "[Transmit](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/transmit/id403388562?mt=12)" you know what it supposed to do but it is making problems. See if there is an [update](http://www.panic.com/transmit/support.html)  or disable it.

Comment: I have closed and terminated processes from both VLC and Transmit and I am still getting the flicking issue.

Comment: so what does now the Console report for WindowServer ? give me all the lines regarding widowserver. could you also publish your screen settings. You said a specific location that is flickering, so it is not the whole screen? Just for fun, could you change your desktop background to plain color.

Comment: Please see updated post, I have changed the colour of my desktop to solid grey, so far so good but I'll keep you updated as its quite temperamental. I I should note that the flickering isnt on the WHOLE screen, a thin line of grainy red blocks appear and flicker for about 10 minutes before they disappear again. I cant seem to capture a screenshot of them but if you want I can draw up a visualisation of them on Photoshop

Comment: Thanks for the Update. Now that we know it is a external monitor, I would guess it is the cable. Why did you down vote my answer?

Comment: I actually have two screens, the problem seems to occur consistently on one screen so I'm gonna try switching the cable and see what happens. (p.s. I didn't vote the answer down)

Comment: Well, some douche bag did, who knows the answer but will not share.